# How to export and import mysql database to ignore Duplicate entries for key 'PRIMARY'?

Tags: mariadb, mysqlimport

I'm attempting to write a bash script that will dump a database and then import it to a staging database. I would like the staging database to match the 'master' database.

I have the following code, however I recieve:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 23: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
# Dump production master database, excluding school_hosts table
mysqldump -h $MYSQL_HOST -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --no-create-info --ignore-table=hcl_master.school_hosts hcl_master > hcl_master.sql

# Dump hcl staging database, for backup.
mysqldump -h $MYSQL_HOST -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD hclstaging_master > hclstaging_master_backup.sql

# Import dump file into staging master database
mysql -h $MYSQL_HOST -u $MYSQL_USERNAME -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD hclstaging_master < hcl_master.sql
```

After searching, I found that I could add --replace to the mysql command that is importing, however I recieve an error stating that:

> mysql: unknown option '--replace'

Can anybody help with getting this script to work correctly? I'm unsure how I can drop the staging database before i import or how to get it to overwrite the primary key record?

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using MariaDB.

Comment: Does this error `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 23: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` not tell you which table is involved?

Comment: Also if you want a exact match between LIVE and STAGING then why are you not exporting all the tables

Comment: I would do a `DROP DATABASE \`hclstaging_master\`; CREATE DATABASE \`hclstaging_master\`;` and then do the import of the COMPLETE hcl_master database backup

Comment: `--replace` is a mysqldump option that you specify when creating the dump, not something you can tell mysql when importing the dump.

Comment: Thanks @ysth, I added --replace to the dump and it's resolved my issue, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

`--replace` is a mysqldump option that you specify when creating the dump, not something you can tell mysql when importing the dump.